# Removing OnGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm using the following code to detect whether or not the keyboard is showing throughout the lifetime of an activity:

```
rootVTO = root.getViewTreeObserver();
    keyboardListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (root.getRootView().getHeight() - root.getHeight() > 150) {
                // Keyboard showing
                isKeyboardShowing = true;
            } else {
                // Keyboard not showing
                isKeyboardShowing = false;
            }

            refreshLayout();
        };
    };
    rootVTO.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardListener);
```

I tried to remove the listener in the onPause() method but get the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver()
```

Will there be a memory leak if I don't remove the listener? If so when should I remove it? Is it sufficient to just set the listener to null?

Comment: Might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972022/why-does-calling-getwidth-on-a-view-in-onresume-return-0/22972145#22972145) help?

Comment: I'm familiar with this thread. I need to keep the listener throughout the activity not just when it is being inflated. 


So, once the activity ends I need to know how to correctly deal with the listener.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the reference after your `Activity` is destroyed -- the Views will no longer be used and will be garbage collected along with your listener. However, if you do need to remove it for some other reason, don't maintain a reference to the `ViewTreeObserver` -- grab the reference from the `View` when you need it. That is, keep a reference to `root`, and when you want to remove the listener, call `root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(keyboardListener)`. The `ViewTreeObserver` instance on the `root` `View` may be replaced, so you could have a stale reference.