# Get height of view programmatically when it is set to Wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a Layout and it's height is set to wrap_content. Now I need to get the real hight dynamically at run time.

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
layout.getLayoutParams().height
```

But this will give me "-2" which is Wrap_Content.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972145/3290339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give like

```
viewObj.getHeight():
```

Instead of this

```
layout.getLayoutParams().height
```

It will be work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the height of layout, that weren't drawn yet.

Use the code snippet below to get the height of the layout

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                height = layout.getHeight(); // here get the height of the view
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

when you getting in view or layout height and width value used below code..

```
 textView = findViewById(R.id.textCurve); // first object define it not null then getting value.

        Log.d("Height Value:::",""+textView.getHeight());// view control or layout object.
```

wrap_content and match parent value given 0.