# When is the Activity root view inflated?

Tags: android, android-view

The docs for the `setContentView()` method in the `Activity` class state that the view is added to the activity window AND inflated. However, the width and height of the root view are both zero after `setContentView()` is called.

Example below:

Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "myTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View root = ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        // Here I expect the root view to have been inflated and have a width and height
        Log.i(TAG, "Root view width:" + root.getWidth() + " height:" + root.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My problem is I need to create a bitmap image of the root view upon the launch of the activity and I'm not sure when I should do this that guarantees the root view has been inflated.

Comment: [Why does calling getWidth() on a View in onResume() return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22972022/3290339)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does calling getWidth() on a View in onResume() return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972022/why-does-calling-getwidth-on-a-view-in-onresume-return-0)

Answer (score 3):

As @Onik correctly commented, he has already answered my question here [Why does calling getWidth() on a View in onResume() return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972022/why-does-calling-getwidth-on-a-view-in-onresume-return-0)

I would add that you could also attach an `addOnLayoutChangeListener` to your view and remove it in `onLayoutChange()`. It's ugly, but seems to be the only way;